# 3D pathing finding with flying

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

How can I enable 3D path finding?  Basically something like:

```
CalculateRoute(input_geometry, start_pos, end_pos, variance)
```

I found a [good paper](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/) on the topic, but I haven't found any solutions via Google or even searching sites like odesk, etc...

I know [recast/detour](http://code.google.com/p/recastnavigation/) is great for ground navigation, but I can't find anything that involves flying/3D space.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I would recommend just implementing A*, A* should work in any euclidean space.

Comment: Isn't A* always shortest path? Is it possible to adapt to have some variance in the path (so it's not always the same + shows some randomness?)

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27090/efficient-path-finding-in-free-space

Comment: Make sure you're not confusing **steering/movement** with **path finding**. As you appear to be by linking the red3d article on steering.

Comment: Do you really need 3D pathing?  Most games get by with regular A* and setting the unit's height using steering or other heuristics/needs.

Answer (score 7):

A* is the go to for most path finding situations. It's no different with 3D spaces, including flying through the air.

Basically, you'll break your game up into nodes. This is called the navigation mesh. These nodes are typically cubes of various sizes. They don't all have to be the same size, you can make large open areas one big cube and the open areas near terrain smaller to have finer precision.

[image]
(unfortunately it appears the site I got this image from originally has gone under. They still have [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pegruZo4g6I) up on Youtube showing this in action though)

Implement A* to use these nodes for path finding. A* is nice because the node cost can be tailored specifically to your game. You can also give multiple nodes the same cost and randomly choose between them to have variances in flight paths. Once you've found the path, now is when you're going to use the red3d link to implement steering. You'll steer towards each node in your path, until you're "close enough", then start steering to the next node. This will give a smooth flight path between a linear node to node path.

Comment: Using this approach, you can only find _some_ path. You can't find the shortest one, you can't impose any constraints on the trajectory, and you suppose the moving object is a zero-size dot. Graph algorithms only work on finite graphs. Even for the much simpler 2D case, when unit can move freely, another methods are usually better, e.g. check out this lecture that mentions some basic methods: http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/mtoussai/teaching/10-robotics/05-paths.pdf

Comment: @Soonts A* will find the shortest path between nodes, not just "some path". It's dependent on your node size and where you pick your points for how short that path can be. You can make the nodes smaller if you want increased precision. You can absolutely limit the trajectory and simulate unit size by limiting the available node transitions (i.e. no sharp u-turns in nodes, no traversing through tiny nodes). Smoother paths is from optimizations after the fact. However, I don't know of any reasonable way to find a path from point A to point B using trajectories alone.

Comment: see this: http://const.me/tmp/a-star-fail.png A graph algorithm (thick lines): yellow=3+sqrt(2) = 4.41, orange=1+2* sqrt(2) = 3.83, orange is shorter
A geometry-based approach (thin straight lines): green= sqrt(5)+sqrt(2)=3.65, red= sqrt(5)+2=4.24, green is shorter.

Comment: If you think the cells are too large here, I can assure you unless your cells are infinitely small (for which you need infinite RAM and CPU), I can come up with an example of the A* failure that leads to totally different path found (keep in mind not only start and end points are in the continuous 2D space, but obstacles as well).

Comment: @Soonts I'd be interested to learn how you're going to use a purely geometry based approach to 3D path finding, and be more efficient than an A* path. You may be thinking about this too hard. Typically, when path finding we're not *that* worried about finding the absolute mathematically shortest path. There's a balance you have to find between finding the shortest path, and finding it quickly. You've yet to suggest an alternative to finding a shorter path *quicker*. See this L4D article about optimizing a A* path: http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2009/ai_systems_of_l4d_mike_booth.pdf

Comment: @Soonts Additionally, the OP never mentions finding the shortest path. And in fact, the second comment on their post indicates they'd be interested in alternatives to the shortest path.

Comment: I never said anything about what approach I will use for the problem, because the TS did not respond to my questions below. I can imagine a gameplay where every moving object is of different size, and for every 2 objects there's a hole in the level geometry through which only one of the objects can pass through. Obviously, your beloved graph algorithms will require heavy modifications to be useful for such game. Of course I know how the pathfinding is traditionally implemented in the 3D shooters: by using 2D algorithms. It may or may not suit the needs of the TS.

Comment: @Soonts I don't think it would take that much modification. Just knowing the size of the entity and the size of the node would be enough. Do you have any resources on 3D pathfinding not using graphs? I'd be interested to read about it.

Comment: those methods are mostly used in real life not games, the keywords for google might be e.g. "autonomous pathfinding". Many approaches to pathfinding use graphs, but those graphs has nothing with regular grid of any kind, instead they're build with complex algorithms from the input geometry, e.g. take a look: https://doclib.uhasselt.be/dspace/bitstream/1942/1158/1/vanwezel-robertus.pdf - only 4 pages out of 60 are devoted to graph algorithms, the rest is about "how to build those graphs from the geometry" and "how to postprocess the path found".

Comment: IMO, most research articles about truly 3D pathfinding were written for the needs of robotics – they have very strict requirements on the quality of the algorithms, and like videogames, controllers for robots must work in realtime. Or maybe it’s just my subjective POV (disclaimer: long time ago I did a lot of R&D with ABB IRB-140 robot).

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent to **Navigation Meshes** for 3D spaces is **Navigation Volumes**.

**Havok AI** implements both navigation volumes and a volume pathfinder as shown in their GDC 2011 demonstration.

The principle of A* in a volume is the same as A* on a navigation mesh.  Since A* will find a path over any graph it doesn't matter if the graph is represented by a point to multiple points, a polygon to multiple polygons, or a volume to multiple volumes.  The algorithm will still find a solution if one exists.

Some slight nuances that are different with paths found on navigation meshes is how you determine path points at the edge of line segments, at the ends, or maybe at the middle?

The same can be true of of navigation volumes, to determine the cost to traverse to the next volume you'll typically have to pick a point within the volume, midpoint/edge/etc.

This all essentially boils down to the heuristic part of the A* algorithm you must supply yourself, or use a basic Euclidean distance algorithm.

**Path Following is not Pathfinding**

How your AI determines to follow this path is something completely different and is referred to as Path Following.  The typical strategy for Path Following is to allow your AI to look ahead of where it's traveling to see if it can short cut the path to make more natural curved movements.

[**Havok AI Demo at GDC 2011**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5nlJPRCLII)

[image: 3D Scene]
*The scene with numerous flying AI's*

[image: Inverted Navigation Volume Scene]
*An inverted view of the navigation volume*